# Need to Use Canvas and Not Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have been asked to fix a bug where the width box is longer than what it should be its dropping off the edge of the screen but I am not allowed to change it from canvas. As you see from the rest of the images the rest of layout is fine i just need to make the width textbox a bit smaller.

In My layout view in visual studio it shows it the right size but on screen it is stretching it??

[image]

```
<Canvas Margin="0,0,-249.6,0">
    <ListView Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="48" Height="183" Name="listView1"
            Width="453" 
            SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order" Width="100" 
                       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsOrder}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Display Name" Width="290" 
                          DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Width" Width="50" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsWidth}"></GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Name="moveUpButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="MoveUp"  Canvas.Top="50" Content="Move Up" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

    <Button Name="moveDownButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" Click="MoveDown" Canvas.Top="80" Content="Move Down" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />


    <Button Name="deleteButton" Canvas.Left="472.4" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=columnsList, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Click="RemoveColumn"   Canvas.Top="110" Content="Delete" 
            Height="22" Width="74"  />

    <Button Name="addButton" Click="AddColumn" Canvas.Left="472.4" Canvas.Top="140" Content="Add Item" 
            Height="22" Width="74" />

    <Label Content="Name:" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="250" />

    <TextBox   Name="txtDsiplayName" Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsDisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"   
            Width="452"  >

    </TextBox>

    <Label Content="Width:"   Canvas.Left="470" Canvas.Top="250" />
    <TextBox  Name="txtWdith"  Text="{Binding Path=CustomColumnsWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"  Canvas.Left="470"  Canvas.Top="280" Height="23"  
            Width="52.8" 
             />

</Canvas>
```

Comment: seems like the issue is not reproducible with the given code.

Comment: @pushpraj well the screen shot dont lie ? im using the wizard frame work but that should not overide the canvas

Comment: I agree that you are facing the issue. What I mean to say that the given code does not seems to be the cause, perhaps some bits are missing from it.

Comment: nope thats all the code that the im using for the canvas i mean

Comment: how do you enter a value 50? from Keyboard or from db?

Comment: from the keyboard thats not what doing it even if blank value its stays streched its not null spaces

Comment: may be just size of the form is smaller then size of left list + Name TextBox and width TextBox?

Comment: pushraj is right. The bug is not part of the code you posted. This works fine. Anyway the person telling you not to use grid here should know that this is the perfect class to use, this is not a canvas scenario imho.

Comment: @Core-One I dont no the grid well enough to incroperate my design into it in the time scale that I have could you provide an example with my type of layout think i can solve my issues 100%